# Override JQuery class selector with css class selector

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have the next HTML code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" style="margin-top: 0;">
   <li>
      <a  data-bind="attr: {href: 'tel:' + person().officePhone}">
            <img class="PersonDetailsUlImage" src="/view/mobile/images/Icon_phone_36x36_drkgry.png" />
            <h6>Office</h6>
            <p data-bind="text: person().officePhone"></p>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

At my CSS file I set my "PersonDetailsUla" class like the next code:

```
.PersonDetailsUla 
{
    padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}
```

When I try to see if my PersonDetailsUla style is working I seeing that Jquery doing override and apply another class:

```
Class="PersonDetailsUla ui-link-inherit"
```

Is there any option to override the padding of ui-link-inherit but be less specific as possible?
If I will use ID selector it will work but I`m trying be less specific as possible.
Thanks

Comment: I assume you are using jQuery Mobile?

Comment: have you tried adding !important to `.PersonDetailsUla `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new css file and include it **after** jquery css file and define your style in your custom stylesheet to override jquery ui styles. So:

```
<!-- jQuery stylesheet-->
<link href="/Content/Styles/jquery-ui-1.8.14.css" media="screen" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Your own custom stylesheet-->
<link href="/Content/Styles/Custom.css" media="screen" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `!important`?

```
padding: 10px !important;
```

Or, you could also use a slightly more specific selector, like this:

```
.PersonDetailsUla.ui-link-inherit {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

This selects all the elements that have both the “personDetails” and the “ui-link-inherit” classes, but it is not as specific as using the ID.

Comment: !important is bed habit - Im trying to avoid from using it.
I have tried using your second suggestion but it didn`t work

Comment: In that case, you can only either use more specific selectors (as in my example), or, if you have other stylesheets, make sure the most important one is loaded last.